# How can I find each name in a range and paste a value below?

Tags: excel, vba, search, find

I'm new to coding and am trying to use vba to search through a range of names and find each name in a different range. After finding that name I need to paste a range value in the next empty cell below. I got it to search the name index range but it doesn't find the matching name in the 2nd range even though it is there. the foundCell range always reads as "Nothing"

Here is the code I have produced so far (with help from google)

```
Sub pasteDate()
With ActiveSheet
Dim dt As Range
Dim indexName As Range
Dim findRng As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Set dt = Range("L15")
Set indexName = Range("Z1:AG12")
Set findRng = Range("B3:Y130")<sub>your text</sub>


For Each element In indexName

         Set foundCell = findRng.Find(element.Value)
         
         
      If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
      
 Range(foundCell & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = dt
 
        End If
    Next element


End With


End Sub
```

[small mock up of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5KUe.png)

Comment: Try specifying all the `Find` parameters in the first instance.

Comment: Try adding the other parameters in the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) function.  Also once `foundcell` finds something it will likely fall over on `Range(foundCell & Rows.Count)` - `foundcell` will be a range object complete with value, formatting, location.  Would `foundCell.Offset(1)` return the correct range?

Comment: Thank you. I added the parameters to the .Find function but it doesn't change anything. The foundCell range remains at "Nothing". Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Think we need more info. Either one of the parameters is wrong or the data is not there.

Comment: the data in formulas if that makes a difference.  for example =$A$35 & "-"& J1 pulls a name from A35 and J1. The element value is name-name. i set the parameter on the find function to lookup:=xlFormulas.

Comment: it appears that if i copy and paste the findRng as values then it is able to pick up the name. is there a way to have it pick up teh name when it is as  the formula?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant to type in LookIn:=xlFormulas. That is what I have it set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code using the provided mock up data. Please make the necessary adjustments to the code to align it with your actual data.

```
Sub pasteDate()

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim dt As Range
        Dim indexName As Range
        Dim findRng As Range
        Dim foundCell As Range
        Dim element As Range
        
        ' Constant for the number of rows below the findRng
        Const dataRows = 3 
        
        ' Set the date cell as the target date (I2)
        Set dt = .Range("I2") ' DT value
        
        ' Set the indexName range 
        Set indexName = .Range("H6:K6")
        
        ' Set the findRng to define the data cells only, not the entire area (A2:F2, A6:F6, A10:F10)
        Set findRng = .Range("A2:F2,A6:F6,A10:F10")
        
        ' Loop through each element in the indexName range
        For Each element In indexName

            Set foundCell = findRng.Find(element.Value)
            
            ' Declare variables for the next empty cell and a counter
            Dim nextCell As Range
            Dim r As Integer
            
            If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
                r = 1
                ' Loop to find the next empty cell within dataRows
                Do While r <= dataRows
                    Set nextCell = foundCell.Offset(r, 0)
                    ' If the next cell is empty, paste the date and exit the loop
                    If IsEmpty(nextCell) Then
                        nextCell = dt
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        ' If no empty cell is found within dataRows, show a message and exit
                        r = r + 1
                        If r > dataRows Then
                        foundCell.Activate
                        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0)).Select
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Selection.Cut Destination:=foundCell.Offset(1)
                        dt.Copy
                        nextCell.Offset(1) = dt
                        nextCell.Offset(1).Interior.Color = dt.Interior.Color
                            Exit Do 'was Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        Next element
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Don, the search values are stored in Z1:AG12 (indexName). The search range is B3:Y130 (findRange). dt is a value in cell L15 that will be changed occasionally. What I'm trying to do is search the findRange for each value in indexName Range and paste the value in range dt  in the next empty cell below the foundCell( this is the range that is searched for). Note that the next empty cell is NOT necessarily the last empty row. any help is appreciated.

Comment: I put a comment in your original code.
1. Start with "." inside of With.
2. Range(foundCell & Rows.Count) won't work as is, we need to put a Column letter there.

Comment: Thank you Don, is there a way to have the dt value put into the next empty cell under the found foundCell? There are more values in cells lower down in the same column so xlUp doesnt work in this instance. it might be that its only one cell down thats empty but it could also be 2 or 3.

Comment: It is not clear to me; "dt value put into the next empty cell under the found foundCell?" Can you give a sample in excel sheet what you want?

Comment: hi vbakin. see excel sheet. note that this is a mock up. the sheet im working on is WAY bigger and uses names instead of numbers. actually, how do i add a sheet?

Comment: Hi vbakin, i have added a picture of a small mock up sheet

Comment: I updated my code  according to your mock up. :)

Comment: Thank you vbakim! that works great! one last thing, i have the DT cell color filled. can i have the foundcell range be made the same color? i had it do that in the code i had (not shown on here) by selecting the cell and pastespecial xlformats.

Comment: I'would add nextCell.Interior.Color = dt.Interior.Color  next to nextCell = dt. 

Don't forget to check my answer as accepted.  :)

Comment: Thank you vbakim! i made your answer the accepted answer. i didn't see your comment till after i edited the code to show what i had done which works as well but i think your idea is better. see the edited code. If the 3 rows are filled, i want the lower 2 to be cut and pasted 1 row up. i got that to work but now after it does one element then it exists the macro... not sure how to get it to go to the next element.

Comment: Can you show in a mock up table, what you are trying to do?  " i want the lower 2 to be cut and pasted 1 row up."

Comment: i have already figured that parts out as shown in the code. but foe some reason, when it finds a match, it goes through the else function the hits exit for then jumps down to End With and End Sub. it needs to keep looping through the nameIndex until it has searched for all of the values...

Comment: How do you want to display the matching result under findRng cells since there are only 3 lines?

Comment: Thanks Vbakim. 3 lines is the max amount i need to see. throughout a year there might be up to 15 DT values inserted but i only need to see back 3 values. I do believe we have got it all figured out and i do thank you for all your help!